# Проблема с анимацией css

Tags: html, css

Сделал анимации, работают, но после окончания анимации, элемент возвращается на стартовую позицию (0%).

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы после выполнения анимации, элемент остался на последней позиции (100%)?

Анимации:

```
@-webkit-keyframes roll-6 {
    0%   {left: 25px;}
    10%  {left: -75px;}
    25%  {left: 75px;}
    50%  {left: -26px;}
    75%  {left: -127px;}
    100% {left: 127px;}
}

@keyframes roll-6 {
    0%   {left: 25px;}
    10%  {left: -75px;}
    25%  {left: 75px;}
    50%  {left: -26px;}
    75%  {left: -127px;}
    100% {left: 127px;}
}

.roll-6 {
    -webkit-animation-name: roll-6;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 3;
    animation-name: roll-6;
    animation-duration: 6s;
    animation-iteration-count: 3;
}
```

Comment: animation-fill-mode: forwards

Comment: дубликат вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/748335/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-animation-css

Comment: создавайте один вопрос, и правьте его по необходимости, не нужно создавать дубли, и лишние аккаунты

Answer (score 1):

`animation-fill-mode: forwards;` не отмотает анимацию или в краткой записи `animation: название длительность forwards;`